# Do I have a memory leak in my WPF Navigation?

Tags: .net, wpf, memory-leaks

I'm looking through a WPF application looking for a memory leak (using ANTS Memory Profiler 5.1) and I keep seeing some pages and controls taking up memory when they shouldn't be.

So I go to the Object Retention Graph and to see what is keeping them around, and I keep seeing this for every page:

[Object Retention Graph http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/3013/ants.jpg](http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/3013/ants.jpg)

The thing is, I have KeepAlive set to false on every page, and I don't think such a property exists on the user controls.

Can anyone tell me what I should be looking for? Is this even a memory leak or is this normal behaviour for a WPF application?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, according to what you've provided, you have a memory leak. When you found the references chain, and it's not in your code, the easiest way to go would be... Reflector.

Image says: `JournalEntryKeepAlive._keepAliveRoot` field holds a reference to the object. Let's go in Reflector and see how this guy is hooked with our object.

This time it was easy, and all traces lead to `NavigationService.MakeJournalEntry()` function and then to `NavigationService.IsContentKeepAlive()`. Here it is:

```
internal bool IsContentKeepAlive()
{
    bool keepAlive = true;
    DependencyObject dependencyObject = this._bp as DependencyObject;
    if (dependencyObject != null)
    {
        keepAlive = JournalEntry.GetKeepAlive(dependencyObject);
        if (!keepAlive)
        {
            PageFunctionBase base2 = dependencyObject as PageFunctionBase;
            bool flag2 = !this.CanReloadFromUri;
            if ((base2 == null) && flag2)
            {
                keepAlive = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return keepAlive;
}
```

Now you know the rules. Object is kept in memory if:

- It's not a dependency object;
- Attached propery JournalEntry.KeepAlive is true;
- It's not a PageFunction and it can't be reloaded from Uri.

After this investigation it may be worth reading more about [JournalEntry.KeepAlive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.keepalive.aspx) property on MSDN.

This strategy helped me to find many memory-related insects. Hope it helps you too :).

PS: If you keep having problem with finding this particular leak, you could paste minimal code sample for us to reproduce it and give you more proper answer.

Cheers,
Anvaka

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, but I'm not sure I follow the DependencyProperty part. If I've set the KeepAlive to be false on every page, why would it still be kept in memory?

Comment: Follow the logical path: even if you set KeepAlive=false on every page, you still can get true from IsContentKeepAlive() when flag2 is true, which says: !CanReloadFromUri

Comment: What did you actually change to let this page be garbage collected?

Comment: This is good research. But it would be nice to know how to work around this issue. Right now my only guess is to remove the back entry, which kind of defeats the whole point of having a NavigationService in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and the same chart with Ants memory analyzer.
The application used a `NavigationWindow` to host some WPF Pages and the navigation was made with this codebehind:

```
NavigationService.Navigate( new Page1());
```

The problem was created by multiple pages kept in memory by the journal and that couldn't be garbage collected.

What i did was to replace the `NavigationWindow` with a normal window, the Pages with UserControls and swap user controls inside the window, like they are pages.
There are many examples on how to do this in google.
After removing all the `NavigationService.Navigate` calls, i could finally garbage collect all the closed pages with Ants memory profiler.

Comment: Clever. But a lot of work. Also, wouldn't you have to develop your own navigation service? I've tried doing that, and it's a real pain.

Comment: Yep, it's building own navigation service. However, it's necessary due to the memory leaks when you do navigations which `!this.CanReloadFromUri` i.e. like `Navigate(new Page());`.